# Making endnotes clickable links with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, endnotes

I would like to use the `endnotes` package, `hyperref` and `biblatex` together to have links to my endnotes. Here is a MWE that shows how the links don't show up:

```
\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
@Book{jones00,
  author =   {Douglas Jones},
  title =    {A book},
  publisher =    {The metasyntactic variable publishing company},
  year =     2000}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage[autocite=footnote,notetype=endonly,style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}
\bibliography{testbib}
\let\footnote\endnote
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Something\autocite[p.12]{jones00} something else\footnote{another endnote?}

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

I'm open to other end-note producing options that work better with `hyperref`, but I'd rather stick with article document class.

Comment: For what it's worth: endnotes produced by the [`enotez`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enotez) package work nicely together with `hyperref`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I once uncovered the following code on comp.text.tex, credited to Ulrich Dirr:

```
%%% hyperendnotes.sty
\makeatletter
\newif\ifenotelinks
\newcounter{Hendnote}
% Redefining portions of endnotes-package:
\let\savedhref\href
\let\savedurl\url
\def\endnotemark{%
\@ifnextchar[\@xendnotemark{%
\stepcounter{endnote}%
\protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@endnote}%
\@endnotemark
}%
}%
\def\@xendnotemark[#1]{%
\begingroup\c@endnote#1\relax
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@endnote}%
\endgroup
\@endnotemark
}%
\def\endnotetext{%
\@ifnextchar[\@xendnotenext{%
\protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@endnote}%
\@endnotetext
}%
}%
\def\@xendnotenext[#1]{%
\begingroup
\c@endnote=#1\relax
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@endnote}%
\endgroup
\@endnotetext
}%
\def\endnote{%
\@ifnextchar[\@xendnote{%
\stepcounter{endnote}%
\protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@endnote}%
\@endnotemark\@endnotetext
}%
}%
\def\@xendnote[#1]{%
\begingroup
\c@endnote=#1\relax
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@endnote}%
\show\@theenvalue
\endgroup
\@endnotemark\@endnotetext
}%
\def\@endnotemark{%
\leavevmode
\ifhmode
\edef\@x@sf{\the\spacefactor}\nobreak
\fi
\ifenotelinks
\expandafter\@firstofone
\else
\expandafter\@gobble
\fi
{%
\Hy@raisedlink{%
\hyper@@anchor{Hendnotepage.\@theenvalue}{\empty}%
}%
}%
\hyper@linkstart{link}{Hendnote.\@theenvalue}%
\makeenmark
\hyper@linkend
\ifhmode
\spacefactor\@x@sf
\fi
\relax
}%
\long\def\@endnotetext#1{%
\if@enotesopen
\else
\@openenotes
\fi
\immediate\write\@enotes{%
\@doanenote{\@theenmark}{\@theenvalue}%
}%
\begingroup
\def\next{#1}%
\newlinechar='40
\immediate\write\@enotes{\meaning\next}%
\endgroup
\immediate\write\@enotes{%
\@endanenote
}%
}%
\def\theendnotes{%
\immediate\closeout\@enotes
\global\@enotesopenfalse
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\edef\@tempa{`\string>}%
\ifnum\catcode\@tempa=12
\let\@ResetGT\relax
\else
\edef\@ResetGT{\noexpand\catcode\@tempa=\the\catcode\@tempa}%
\@makeother\>%
\fi
\def\@doanenote##1##2##3>{%
\def\@theenmark{##1}%
\def\@theenvalue{##2}%
\par
\smallskip %<-small vertical gap between endnotes
\begingroup
\def\href{\expandafter\savedhref}%
\def\url{\expandafter\savedurl}%
\@ResetGT
\edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@endnote\endcsname\@theenmark}%
\enoteformat
}%
\def\@endanenote{%
\par\endgroup
}%
% Redefine, how numbers are formatted in the endnotes-section:
\renewcommand*\@makeenmark{%
\hbox{\normalfont\@theenmark~}%
}%
% header of endnotes-section
\enoteheading
% font-size of endnotes
\enotesize
\input{\jobname.ent}%
\endgroup
}%
\def\enoteformat{%
\rightskip\z@
\leftskip1.8em
\parindent\z@
\leavevmode\llap{%
\setcounter{Hendnote}{\@theenvalue}%
\addtocounter{Hendnote}{-1}%
\refstepcounter{Hendnote}%
\ifenotelinks
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\fi
{\@firstofone}%
{\hyperlink{Hendnotepage.\@theenvalue}}%
{\makeenmark}%
}%
}%
% stop redefining portions of endnotes-package:
\makeatother
% Toggle switch in order to turn on/off back-links in the
% endnote-section:
\enotelinkstrue
%\enotelinksfalse
```

Load it with the `endnotes` package (*after* `hyperref`) and enjoy.

Comment: Beware that `hyperendnote.sty` appears in at least two completely different versions on comp.text.tex, and one of them doesn't work as well as this one.

Comment: Jeez, this seems like an awful lot of extra code for what I thought was a simple problem...

Comment: @Seamus: Those hyperlinks have to come from somewhere (you were expecting them to come from `endnotes`; this is basically a reimplementation that does this).  Also, in case it wasn't clear, you should copy all that code into a file (say, `hyperendnotes.sty`) and `\input` or `\usepackage` it.  So no extra code goes into the actual document.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this is not a `biblatex` issue. The `hyperref` README states on page 18 that the endnotes package is "[u]nsupported".

Answer (score 1):

Use the enotez package (\usepackage{enotez}).

For details see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228296/42648

Comment: This is rather a comment then an answer.

Answer (score 1):

enotez works well, but we had a problem when it was used together with a large collection of style files. Instead, defined a simple mod of endnotes that worked in that environment. Also used two options where you can click either on the note number or on the text marked with that number. The latter seems useful for small font displayed on a tablet when it is difficult to hit the very small note number. Here is a complete example.

```
% A simple macro that uses endnotes with hyperref
% (by Giovanni Rinaldi and Klaus Truemper)
%
% Important: the command \setcounter{notelabelcount}{0} needs
%            to go just before \theendnotes
%
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 0} % Uncomment if you want to get rid 
                              % of the box highlighting the link
\usepackage{endnotes}

% hyperref of notes
\newcounter{notelabelcount}
\setcounter{notelabelcount}{0}
\def\HyperRaiseLinkDefault{12pt} % Replace 12pt with \baselineskip or
                                 % any other suitable length
% this macro makes the note number become the link to the endnote
\newcommand{\mysimplenote}[1]{%
   \addtocounter{notelabelcount}{1}%
   \hyperref[notelabel\thenotelabelcount]{%
   \endnote{%
      \addtocounter{notelabelcount}{1}%
      \phantomsection\label{notelabel\thenotelabelcount}%
      {#1}%
   }}%
}

% this macro makes some text (1st parameter) become the link to 
% the endnote (second parameter)
\newcommand{\mynote}[2]{%
   \addtocounter{notelabelcount}{1}%
   \hyperref[notelabel\thenotelabelcount]{#1}%
   \endnote{%
      \addtocounter{notelabelcount}{1}%
      \phantomsection\label{notelabel\thenotelabelcount}%
      {#2}%
   }%
}

\begin{document}
RODERIGO:
Tush! Never tell me. I take it much unkindly
That thou, Iago, who hast had my purse
As if the strings were thine, shouldst know of
this\mysimplenote{W.~Shakespeare, Othello, Act 1, Scene 1.}.

MONTANO: 
Methinks the wind hath spoke aloud at land,
A fuller blast ne'er shook our battlements.
If it hath ruffianed so upon the sea
What ribs of oak, when mountains melt on them,
Can hold the mortise? What shall we hear of
this?\mysimplenote{W.~Shakespeare, Othello, Act 2, Scene 1.}

OTHELLO:
Get you to bed on th' instant, I will be returned
Forthwith. Dismiss your attendant there, 
\mynote{look't be done}{W.~Shakespeare, Othello, Act 4, Scene 3.}.

\newpage

\setcounter{notelabelcount}{0} % this is necessary
\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: SInce I am the maintainer of `enotez` I am curious: when you say »`enotez` works well, but we had a problem when it was used together with a large collection of style files« was the problem related to/caused by `enotez`? Are you able to reproduce the problem in a minimal example so I can investigate and maybe provide a fix for `enotez`?

Comment: The problem occurred with use of the tufte_style class, which uses numerous style files and which we have changed significantly. Constructing a small example is not possible due  to the complexity of the tufte_style class files. Sorry that we cannot be of more help.

Comment: Thanks. Since `enotez` is compatible with `tufte-latex` obviously some of the modifications caused problems. That's OK: a package author cannot predict individual changes…