# Is it possible for the printed output to show the endnote boxes?

Tags: hyperref, endnotes

I have a Latex document that include endnotes. I have adapted this document to show the boxed links in black using hyperref. The PDF output is as I wanted.

MWE:
    %

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\input{hyperendnotes.sty}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\hypersetup{
  linkbordercolor=Black
}

Sample Text Sample Text \footnote{This endnote shows the color frame with the corresponding footnote (endnote number)}

\begingroup
\parskip 2ex
\theendnotes
\endgroup


\end{document}
```

A version of hyperendnotes.sty can be found [here](https://github.com/bibliogum/latexamu/blob/master/hyperendnotes.sty). I have included xcolor for convenience to change the color of the frame in each endnote number to black.

However, I need the printed output to show these boxes as well. In the current version, the boxes in the endnotes disapear in the printed document (which is the common behaviour !).

Is there any chance to change this default behaviour such that the printed output shows these endnote boxes ?

The final goal is to be able to print the PDF without the Notes section, but still be able to highlight the position of these notes in the main text (hence the black box).

I have tried to change the way in which the number of each endnote is framed, but there is a clash between hyperref and endnote packages.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please make your example [minimal](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Does it use `blindtext`? Why do you load both `color` and `xcolor`? Could you post a link to `hyperendnotes.sty`, e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8452/making-endnotes-clickable-links-with-hyperref/8474#8474, as this is probably not part of most of our distributions...

Comment: Please edit in responses to the questions posed in the comment above.