# Problem with converting footnotes into endnotes

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, footnotes, endnotes

I'm using `endnotes` package to create endnotes, and since my existing body of text already contains lots of footnotes, `I use \let\footnote=\endnote` to convert footnotes into endnotes.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{endnotes}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \let\footnote=\endnote
    \begin{document}
    Sample text.\footnote{Sample footnote}.
    \theendnotes
    \end{document}
```

But while the original footnotes were nicely cross-referenced, the conversion doesn't preserve that. Is there a way to make a conversion while preserving the cross-referencing?

Comment: What do you mean? The question is unclear to me.

Comment: Normally, the footnote number in the body of the text just takes you to the text in the footnote. That's not preserved with the conversion to the endnotes I provide above (the endnote no. doesn't take you to the endnote text).

Comment: The default latex footnotes are not hyperlinked, you might ne used to hyperref?

Comment: Thanks. I am using hyperref to get the footnotes be cross-referenced in the first place. But not sure how to modify when converting to endnotes.

Comment: See if this helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8452/27635

Comment: You should use [`enotez`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enotez), it was developed to provide – amongst other things – support for `hyperref`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to make `hyperref` work with endnotes, you could use [`enotez`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enotez). All you have to do is load `enotez` instead of `endnotes` and use `\printendnotes` instead of `\theendnotes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backref]{enotez}      % <-- instead of \usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}
    Sample text.\footnote{Sample footnote}.
\printendnotes           % <-- instead of \theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Edit: If you want back references from the notes to the mark in the text, then use the option `backref`

Update: Newer versions of `enotez` are set differently (see remark in the comments)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{backref=true} % <-- options are set like this nowadays  

\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}
    Sample text.\footnote{Sample footnote}.
\printendnotes           
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works, but I do get an error message ("LaTeX error:"kernel/command-already-defined" "control sequence !\endnote already defined.") This happens regardless of whether I just replace all instances of \footnote with \endnote or if I do it via \let\footnote=\endnote.

Comment: Clearly, it must be due to some other package I'm loading but not sure which one is to blame.

Comment: Looks like it's due to mdwlist but I have no idea why.

Comment: `mdwlist` is rather old . . . is there any particular reason why you are using it and not [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/enumitem/enumitem.pdf)?

Comment: I want to be able to use `\resume{enumerate}` `\suspend{enumerate}` sequencing to coordinate numbered lists. This breaks down with `enumitem`

Comment: a) enumitem can do [`\begin{enumerate}[resume]`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/resuming-a-list) b) you should ask a new question with a new MWE, as this has nothing to do with converting endnotes to footnotes (and hyperref)  anymore.

Comment: right, that might work. i was looking for a minimal change to the body of the text i already have. thanks!

Comment: Does not work for me :( - although I am tryin to do slightly different thing. I do not turn all foonotes into endotes, but rather use \endnote in the document directly. \footnotes are "backlinked" correctly, but not endnotes.

Comment: @gorn You should ask a new question and post a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: This works for me but hyperref works from the numbers in the body of the text to the numbers of endnotes but not vice versa. How to make hyperref work the other way around too?

Comment: In the enotez manual on page 4: set the option `backref`

Comment: For anyone trying to do that in 2023 :
```\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{backref=true}
```

Comment: Thanks @fyusuf-a! I updated the answer