# Clickable footnote and endnote links with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, endnotes

I want to include clickable links in my document that take you from a footnote or endnote in the body text to some material in the appendix. This problem is similar to the one posed in [Making endnotes clickable links with hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8452/making-endnotes-clickable-links-with-hyperref), so I tried to use the `hyperendnotes.sty` code in Ryan Reich's answer to do so.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{endnotes} 
\let\footnote\endnote
\renewcommand\enoteheading{\chapter{Notes}}
\renewcommand\enoteformat{\leftskip=0pt \parindent=0em
  \leavevmode\makeenmark\raggedright}

\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperendnotes}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter}

\section{section}
first\footnote{hello}, 

second\endnote{this is my equation
\begin{equation}
z=x+y
\end{equation}
}

third\endnote{another equation $a+b+c$}

\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notes}

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

The result looks OK:
[image]

but I get errors like `Undefined control sequence. first\footnote{hello}` and when I click on the links I am taken back to the first page. How do I fix this?

Comment: There's a comment below Ryan Reich's answer that suggests you should `copy all that code into a file (say, hyperendnotes.sty) and \input or \usepackage it. So no extra code goes into the actual document.`

Comment: And an other comment of Ryan: **Load it with the endnotes package (*after* hyperref) and enjoy.**

Comment: So the order should be `hyperref`, `endnotes`, `hyperendnotes`? In that case I'm still getting the same error message

Comment: Please see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228289/problem-with-converting-footnotes-into-endnotes