# Link does not work properly with endnotes and hyperref when endnote counter is reset

Tags: hyperref, endnotes

I am trying to creatate circular hyperlinks between endnotes marks and their respective content. I ended up finding [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479444/link-does-not-work-with-endnotes-and-hyperref-sty#answer-479466) that basicaly does what I want. However, in my project the endnote counter is reseted each chapter, what makes the code to fail.

I modified the original code a little trying to fix it. I created a new counter `glenote` that is never reseted. I am triying to use it to create unique labels and hyperrefs for each endnote, but because some reason the links just work from the endnotes body to their marks. The straight path (from the endnote mark to its content) just works until I reset the `endnote` counter.

Below is the code with the modifications I made.

```tex
\begin{filecontents*}{hyperendnote.sty}
%%% hyperendnotes.sty
\makeatletter
\newif\ifenotelinks
\newcounter{Hendnote}
\newcounter{glenote}
% Redefining portions of endnotes-package:
\let\savedhref\href
\let\savedurl\url
\def\endnotemark{%
\@ifnextchar[\@xendnotemark{%
\stepcounter{endnote}%
\stepcounter{glenote}%
\protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@glenote}%
\@endnotemark
}%
}%
\def\@xendnotemark[#1]{%
\begingroup\c@glenote#1\relax
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@glenote}%
\endgroup
\@endnotemark
}%
\def\endnotetext{%
\@ifnextchar[\@xendnotenext{%
\protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@glenote}%
\@endnotetext
}%
}%
\def\@xendnotenext[#1]{%
\begingroup
\c@glenote=#1\relax
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@glenote}%
\endgroup
\@endnotetext
}%
\def\endnote{%
\@ifnextchar[\@xendnote{%
\stepcounter{endnote}%
\stepcounter{glenote}%
\protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@glenote}%
\@endnotemark\@endnotetext
}%
}%
\def\@xendnote[#1]{%
\begingroup
\c@glenote=#1\relax
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenmark{\theendnote}%
\unrestored@protected@xdef\@theenvalue{\number\c@glenote}%
\show\@theenvalue
\endgroup
\@endnotemark\@endnotetext
}%
\def\@endnotemark{%
\leavevmode
\ifhmode
\edef\@x@sf{\the\spacefactor}\nobreak
\fi
\ifenotelinks
\expandafter\@firstofone
\else
\expandafter\@gobble
\fi
{%
\Hy@raisedlink{%
\hyper@@anchor{Hendnotepage.\@theenvalue}{\empty}%
}%
}%
\hyper@linkstart{link}{Hendnote.\@theenvalue}%
\makeenmark
\hyper@linkend
\ifhmode
\spacefactor\@x@sf
\fi
\relax
}%
\long\def\@endnotetext#1{%
\if@enotesopen
\else
\@openenotes
\fi
\immediate\write\@enotes{%
\@doanenote{\@theenmark}{\@theenvalue}%
}%
\begingroup
\def\next{#1}%
\newlinechar='40
\immediate\write\@enotes{\meaning\next}%
\endgroup
\immediate\write\@enotes{%
\@endanenote
}%
}%
\def\theendnotes{%
\immediate\closeout\@enotes
\global\@enotesopenfalse
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\edef\@tempa{`\string>}%
\ifnum\catcode\@tempa=12
\let\@ResetGT\relax
\else
\edef\@ResetGT{\noexpand\catcode\@tempa=\the\catcode\@tempa}%
\@makeother\>%
\fi
\def\@doanenote##1##2##3>{%
\def\@theenmark{##1}%
\def\@theenvalue{##2}%
\par
\smallskip %<-small vertical gap between endnotes
\begingroup
\def\href{\expandafter\savedhref}%
\def\url{\expandafter\savedurl}%
\@ResetGT
\edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@glenote\endcsname\@theenvalue}%
\enoteformat
}%
\def\@endanenote{%
\par\endgroup
}%
% Redefine, how numbers are formatted in the endnotes-section:
\renewcommand*\@makeenmark{%
\hbox{\normalfont\@theenmark~}%
}%
% header of endnotes-section
\enoteheading
% font-size of endnotes
\enotesize
\input{\jobname.ent}%
\endgroup
}%
\def\enoteformat{%
\rightskip\z@
\leftskip1.8em
\parindent\z@
\leavevmode\llap{%
\setcounter{Hendnote}{\@theenvalue}%
\addtocounter{Hendnote}{-1}%
\refstepcounter{Hendnote}%
\ifenotelinks
\expandafter\@secondoftwo
\else
\expandafter\@firstoftwo
\fi
{\@firstofone}%
{\hyperlink{Hendnotepage.\@theenvalue}}%
{\makeenmark}%
}%
}%
% stop redefining portions of endnotes-package:
\makeatother
% Toggle switch in order to turn on/off back-links in the
% endnote-section:
\enotelinkstrue
%\enotelinksfalse
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[%  
  pdftex
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{endnotes}

%\makeatletter
%\newbox\endnotebox%
%\setbox\endnotebox=\hbox{11}%
%
%\newlength{\enotehangalign}%
%\setlength{\enotehangalign}{13\p@}%
%
%\AtBeginDocument{%
  %\def\enoteformat{%
  %\def\@makeenmark{\hbox to \wd\endnotebox{\hss{\normalfont\@theenmark}}}%
  %\rightskip\z@ \leftskip\z@ \parindent=\z@\parskip\z@\def\@textsuperscript{}\hangindent\enotehangalign%
    %\leavevmode{\makeenmark\ignorespaces\enskip\ignorespaces}\RaggedRight}%
  %\def\enoteheading{\section*{Notes}%
  %}%
  %\def\enotesize{\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont}%
%}%
%\@addtoreset{endnote}{chapter}%
%\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperendnote}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test 1}
This is for test\endnote{Test}. 
This is for test\endnote{Test 2}. 
This is for test\endnote{Test 3}. 
This is for test\endnote{Test 4}. 
This is for test\endnote{Test 5}. 
This is for test\endnote{Test 6}. 
This is for test\endnote{Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 
  Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7
  Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 
  Test 7 Test 7 Test 7 Test 7}. 
This is for test\endnote{Test 8}. 
\setcounter{endnote}{0}%}
% from this line onwards the straight link
% between the endnote mark and its content sticks to the
% first endnote 8
This is for test\endnote{Test 2.1}. 
This is for test\endnote{Test 2.2}. 
This is for test\endnote{Test 2.3}.
This is for test\endnote{Test 2.4}. 
This is for test\endnote{Test 2.5}. 
This is for test\endnote{Test 2.6}.
This is for test\endnote{Test 2.7}. 
This is for test\endnote{Test 2.8}. 
This is for test\endnote{Test 2.9}.

\clearpage

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what exactly the problem is with the example? I have no idea what you man by `the straight path (from the endnote mark to its content) just works until I reset the endnote counter.` What `straight path`?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean by a `straight path` is a link from the note marker, in the body of the text, to the note content at the end of the document. It's the ref, not the back ref.

Comment: @daleif after I reset the `endnote` counter, the markers of notes 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8 and 2.9 points to `Test 8`